# Is there a way to represent int value in byte over 127 without doing bitwise operations?

Tags: java

I am really short on time for doing the learning of bitwise operations.
I want to convert large integer(>127) values without doing '<<' or anything similar.

I need byte representation of integer values used to identify sequence numbers of packets in header sent across UDP. If there is no solution I will introduce two bytes..

Something like: 1, 1 ; 1,2 ; 1,3 ; packet lost ; 1,4 ; packet lost; 2,1 ,2,2
 and then reset it upon reaching 127; 127

I can introduce third, but this is rather ugly.

It would be really useful to have black box that is part of java api doing all that byte conversion for me. Is there?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you have against bitwise operators?

Comment: absolutely nothing to offend you or other people using it :-) It is just sometimes(really rare case of non critical systems) finishing job in time is more important, than using the correct method which will require time to learn :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pack an unsigned 8-bit value into a `byte`:

```
static byte toByte(int i) {
  if ((i < 0) || (i > 255))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(i));
  return (byte) i;
}
```

To convert back:

```
static int toInt(byte b) {
  return (b < 0) ? (b + 256) : b;
}
```

---

After reading your comments on other answers, it sounds like you might want something like this:

```
byte[] b = BigInteger.valueOf(counter).toByteArray();
```

and

```
long counter = new BigInteger(b).longValue();
```

Since the length of the array would vary as the counter grows, you'd need some way to indicate its length or delimit it. But this technique will convert any integer value to an array of bytes.

Comment: I may have phrased my questions incorrectly, I know how to convert 8 bit values. What about large values like >256 where you throw exception, that need two bytes at least to be represented? Can this conversion be done with the same level of simplicity?

Comment: Oh yes! Seems to be what I am expecting! Let me just test this and I will accept :-) Thousand thanks.

Comment: FYI, I updated my answer to include converting values to byte arrays without an intermediate `BigInteger` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that you want *unsigned* bytes, as in, numbers between 128 and 255 inclusive?

That's...tricky.  The Java language won't let you directly treat bytes as unsigned...but with library support it gets a little easier.  [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides an [UnsignedBytes](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html) utility class for some of these needs.  Addition, multiplication, and subtraction are all exactly the same on signed and unsigned bytes.

*EDIT:* Judging from your additional comments, you might be interested in [Ints.toByteArray(int)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toByteArray%28int%29) and the like, which work on types between `byte` and `BigInteger`.

Comment: well not just range 0 - 255 , whatever max possible actually. So that I would have minimum number of sequence values resets whenever reaching the maximum range value. I already can do it even with signed since I can start counting from -127 to 127, it is not an issue but still header range of possible values is really small. I will try to implement with what is available and see how it goes. The question is about whether you can automatically convert say 999999 integer number to byte.

Comment: That number can't fit in a byte.  Ever.  You'll need a bigger type.  Possibly a byte array.

Answer (score -2):

According to my understanding, you want to separate an int into 4 bytes. If so, then just copy paste this code:

```
int i = /* your int */

int[] b = { (i >> 24) & 0xff, (i >> 16) & 0xff, (i >> 8) & 0xff, i & 0xff };
```

Indices 0-3 are each of the 4 bytes in the int.